# How to Convert System.Drawing.Font to iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont?

Tags: c#, winforms, itext

I want to add a watermark on some pdf. And I used iTextSharp to do this function. but how can I convert Font to BaseFont? I have Searched a lot and got nothing helpful.

```
font = new System.Drawing.Font("cambria", 26f, FontStyle.Bold);
BaseFont basefont = BaseFont.CreateFont(font);
```

Answer (score 1):

Now I find the way to convert...

```
private static BaseFont ConvertFont2BaseFont(System.Drawing.Font _font)
{
    var fontFolderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts);
            
    if(!FontFactory.IsRegistered(_font.Name)) FontFactory.RegisterDirectory(fontFolderPath);
    BaseFont baseFont = FontFactory.GetFont(_font.Name, _font.Size, ConvertFontStyle(_font.Style)).BaseFont;
    return baseFont;
}

private static int ConvertFontStyle(FontStyle _fontStyle)
{
    int style = -1;
            
    if((_fontStyle & FontStyle.Regular) != 0)
    {
        style |= iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL;
    }
    if((_fontStyle & FontStyle.Bold) != 0)
    {
        style |= iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD;
    }
    if((_fontStyle & FontStyle.Italic) != 0)
    {
        style |= iTextSharp.text.Font.ITALIC;
    }                    
    if((_fontStyle & FontStyle.Underline) != 0)
    {
        style |= iTextSharp.text.Font.UNDERLINE;
    }
    if((_fontStyle & FontStyle.Strikeout) != 0)
    {
        style |= iTextSharp.text.Font.STRIKETHRU;
    }
    return style;
}
```